# How to check the array values, what WP_Query has brought to me?

Tags: wp-query, query

I have two questions in a row:

- How to check the array values, what `WP_Query` has brought to me?
- If I get 10 posts in cat=3, then I want to get only 5 from them, and then want to echo them individually wherever I want them to print.

It may be like:

```
-------------------
| 1  |  2         |
-------------------
| 3 | 4 |
-------------------
| 5 |
-------------------
```

But I don't have any idea on both of the problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you start with:

```
$custom_query_args = array( 
    'cat' => 10,
    'post_per_page' => 5
);

$custom_query = new WP_Query($custom_query_args);
```

Then to answer your first question, you can see what is returned (for development/debugging) via:

```
var_dump( $custom_query );
```

To output your query as a normal loop, you simply need to call a custom loop, using the `have_posts()` and `the_post()` member functions of the Query class:

```
// Start loop
if ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $custom_query->have_posts() ) : $custom_query->the_post();
    // Loop output goes here
// End loop
endwhile; endif;
// Restore $post data to the default query
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$custom_query = new WP_Query($custom_query_args);` or does it automatically match it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The posts retrieved from a query are stored in the variable named `posts`. You can read or modify that array as you wish. For example if the `WP_Query` object is `$query`, you can do `$posts = $query->posts;`

For your next question, just don't use the while & display them wherever you like

```
if(have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    the_title();
}

// some other code

if(have_posts()) {
    the_post();
    the_title();
}
```

`the_post()` sets the current post to the next post in the objects posts array. The rest is just pure php

Comment: I would not recommend conflating core-defined query variables with custom queries. It just leads to problems.

Comment: As long as you not touch the global `$wp_query` & also take care of all the other object variables such as `post_count`, modifying `posts` variable works fine. `WP_Query` class is flexible enough for that & in case we ever reach a use case where that's not enough, we can extend the class to suit our needs. :)